# Ul and LI items before and after all aligned orizontally

Tags: html, css

Our web designer wants a vertical UL / LI list like the following image.

[image: What we are attempting to obtain]

But using this style I obtained

[image]

the stye was the following

```
    <style type="text/css">
ul {
    list-style: none;

}
ul li:after {
    content: "\25BC \0020";
}

ul li:before {
    content: "\25A0 \0020"; color:#C60;
}
</style>
```

Im going to pass to a table but is there a way to obtain an aligned list also if the line owerflows ?

Comment: try to add `display: inline-block` to `:after` and `:before`

Comment: no luck !! Tried but the result is the same with FireFox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZP7cZ/3/) works pretty nice, note that the li left-margin and text-indent depend on the icon used, but like this they keep their alignment even with changing font-sizes.

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul li {
    text-indent: -0.88em;
    margin-left: 0.88em;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

ul li:before {
    content: "\25A0";
    color: #C60;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin-right: .25em;
}

ul li:after {
    color: #C60;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
}
```

Edit: `vertical-align: text-bottom;` results in a better icon-to-text alignment in FF for me.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set position: relative of the parent, the ul, and position: relative of the before / after pseudo elements.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
ul li:after {
  content: "\25BC \0020";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  content: "\25A0 \0020"; color:#C60;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QgBvb/

Comment: I assume your update is http://jsfiddle.net/QgBvb/1/. So, what's wrong? The drop-down arrow is not centered when the text wraps?

Comment: If so, I would probably use a background image, positioned right / center instead of :after pseudo. Otherwise you'll have to introduce additional DOM elements which is bad. Makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div > 
                    <ul>
                        <li> </li>
                            <li class="first"><a href="f.php">Fragrances</a></li>
                                <li> </li>
                            <li><a href="c.php">Cosmetics</a></li>
                        <li> </li> 
                        <li><a href="s.php">Stuffed Toys</a></li>
                       <li> </li>
                        <li><a href="b.php">Housing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

</body>
</html>
```

copy this is a new file and see the result, u jus have to use li and ul correctly

Comment: Where is css? Please use jsfiddle.net for examples and here put only the relevant part of the code.